# How to resolve based on lifetime scope name?

Tags: c#, autofac, masstransit

I have a project with multiple logical services (queues) in the same windows service and I'm trying to configure each to have it's own log file. So I'm setting up named instances of the file manager:

```
cb.RegisterType<LogFileHandler>()
  .Named<LogFileHandler>("Project1")
  .WithParameter("filename", "c:\\project1.txt")
  .SingleInstance();
cb.RegisterType<LogFileHandler>()
  .Named<LogFileHandler>("Project2")
  .WithParameter("filename", "c:\\project2.txt")
  .SingleInstance();
```

The MassTransit integration creates a named/tagged scope for each service but there doesn't seem to be a way to get this information in the registration. For instance, it would be great if I could do something like this:

```
cb.Register((x) => x.ResolveNamed<LogFileHandler>(x.Tag))
```

x.Tag doesn't exist however, so is there a way of discriminating based on scope name? Or a better approach in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve a `ILifetimeScope` to get the `Tag` information on the register method.

```
builder.RegisterType<LogFileHandler>()
       .Named<LogFileHandler>("Project1")
       .WithParameter("filename", "c:\\project1.txt")
       .SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<LogFileHandler>()
       .Named<LogFileHandler>("Project2")
       .WithParameter("filename", "c:\\project2.txt")
       .SingleInstance();


builder.Register(c => {
            String tag = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>().Tag as String; 
            return c.ResolveNamed<LogFileHandler>(tag); 
       })
       .As<LogFileHandler>();
```

It should works but if you have a child scope or a `Owned` dependency `Tag` won't be present in this resolved `ILifetimeScope`. To fix this you can resolve a `ISharingLifetimeScope` and check the `Parent` property.

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    String tag;
    ISharingLifetimeScope scope = c.Resolve<ISharingLifetimeScope>();
    while (scope != null)
    {
        if (scope.Tag is String
            && new String[] { "Project1", "Project2" }.Contains((String)scope.Tag))
        {
            tag = (String)scope.Tag;
            break;
        }

        scope = scope.ParentLifetimeScope;
    }
    return c.ResolveNamed<LogFileHandler>(tag);
})
.As<LogFileHandler>();
```

`ISharingLifetimeScope` will be resolved to `null` only if you resolve something directly from the `IContainer` and not from a child lifetime scope.

Comment: Brilliant, I never would of thought of that. The first solution is more than adequate for now.